# Tool to aggregate error messages in Windows event logs?

Tags: windows, windows-event-log

Is there a simple way to filter out only errors and warnings in a Windows event log, and apply aggregate functions like 'count and group by error type', 'message' or 'code'?

Comment: PowerShell works well. See also: [Microsoft's Log Parser](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659)

Answer (score 2):

You could export the log to csv, then you can unleash all the excel-power you want.

```
Get-EventLog Application | Export-Csv ApplicationLog.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Powershell has some functions for this and log parser (with log parser lizard if you want a GUI) works well. This is especially true I'd you like SQL syntax.

Splunk or another log analysis engine are also good candidates.